# Microservices Concurrent Payments on The Same Account

Tags: concurrency, locking, microservices

Let us say that we have a transaction microservice that transfers money from one account to another account using mysql as the data store.

Let us say that there is a request called K to transfer money from account A to account B. There is also another request Z from Account A to Account C concurrently to transfer money. My question is what strategy should a transaction microservice use when Account B is locked during processing? Should request Z time out and return an error, should request Z try multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for financial transactions is:
1.Any transaction on account A is a put into a queue that must have account A in the transaction. Let us call this queue QueueA. There is some code that will process transaction on QueueA, maybe a separate thread.
2.If there is any new transaction request, check the accounts involved in the transaction. If there is a queue with one of the accounts added to it, then add that transaction into that queue, if not create a new queue and add the transaction there.

The idea is to linearlize processing of transactions on the same account. This prevents database connection from blocking and timing out. Also, use optimistic database locking by adding a version column on each table. This insures data integrity in financial systems as opposed to pessimistic locking which might cause database connections from timing out.